# Counting matching rows of two same tables and counting rows of the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the same table structure called "table1" under two different schemas "schema1" and "schema2". "table1" contains columns "col1, col2, col3". Initialy I want see whether there are records having the same entries of `col1` and `col2` in the table `schema1.table1` and `schema2.table1`. But I had mistyped `schema2.table1` as `schema1.table1`. And now I am confused by the query result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema1.table1 AS s1t, schema1.table1 AS s2t
WHERE s1t.col1 = s2t.col1 AND s1t.col2 = s2t.col2;
```

I got

```
 count 
-------
   530
(1 row)
```

However, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema1.table1;` shows that there are 17815 rows.

Why would the first query show there are only 530 satisfied records? Shouldn't it be 17815 as well?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Any null values in the table? Such rows will not be counted here. Do `select count(*) from schema1.table1 where col1 is null or col2 is null`.

Comment: @jarlh Okay the returned query result plus 530 does add up to 17815...I didn't know about I can't do something like `NULL = NULL` in sql.

Comment: e.g. `select count(*) from table1 where col1 = col1` is the same as `select count(*) from table1 where col1 is not null`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-full-outer-join.php) to see even mismatched rows, including null values for columns(col1 and 2). This way, at least(more than or equal to) 17815 rows return

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM schema1.table1 AS s1t
  FULL OUTER JOIN schema1.table1 AS s2t
    ON s1t.col1 = s2t.col1 AND s1t.col2 = s2t.col2
```

In your case, only matched rows return for those columns (col1 and 2).

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the table to itself.  That is really strange.

In any case, your `join` is going to filter out any rows where `col1` or `col2` are `NULL`.

In addition, the self-join might multiply the number of rows if there are duplicates (with respect to the two columns) in the table.

It is really unclear why you would be doing this, but the above explains the results you are seeing.

If you want to compare the results in the two schemas *allowing for duplicates and missing values*, I recommend `union all`/`group by`:

```
select col1, col2, sum(cnt1) as cnt1, sum(cnt2) as cnt2
from ((select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt1, 0 as cnt2
       from schema1.table1
       group by col1, col2
      ) union all
      (select col1, col2, 0 as cnt1, count(*) as cnt2
       from schema2.table1
       group by col1, col2
      )
     ) t12
group by col1, col2
having sum(cnt1) <> sum(cnt2);
```

This returns pairs where the counts are not the same in the two tables.  It even works for `NULL` values.  If you ran this on the same table, no rows would be returned.

Comment: _I had mistyped schema2.table1 as schema1.table1_